# Open file based on latest version and count rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to open latest version of a specific file in a folder. I then wish to count the total number of rows and return the value in cell (K,2) in this workbook. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub CountRows()


    Dim SourceLocation As String
    Dim EndLocation As String
    Dim File As String
    Dim strdays As Integer
    Dim FSO As Object

    Dim f, f1, fc


    strdays = 2
    SourceLocation = "H:\location\"



    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = FSO.GetFolder(SourceLocation)
    Set fc = f.Files
    Dim LastRow As Long

    For Each f1 In fc
        If DateDiff("d", f1.DateLastModified, Date) < strdays And LCase(Left(f1.Name, 6)) = "myFile" Then
            Workbooks.Open f1
            LastRow = f1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            f1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 20).Value = LastRow

    Exit For

End If

Next

End Sub
```

At the moment, this function opens the file but breaks when it gets to counting number of rows.

Comment: The coloring of the code shows, that you forgot a " on the `LastRow = ...` line. Does that already fix it?

Comment: No unfortunately not - didn't copy properly from VBA file. @Czeskleba

Comment: `Dim wb as Workbook`  then `set wb = Workbooks.Open(f1)`  and then use wb not f1.  f1 is not a excel workbook object.

Comment: it's also `Workbooks.Open(f1.Path)` not just the f1

Comment: Sorceri is right and that should fix it. Also, consider doing this with a query. It should be faster. You could also add the filepath to a cell close to it to make changes to it easily.